# Swift 3 .If I will use google Maps in my project (google sdk) will the user need to instal google maps before using it?

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, swift3

Swift 3. If I use google Maps in my project (google sdk) and whenever user will open  View Controller with this maps will the user need to download google maps or it will work straight away even if user haven't got installed google maps?

Thank you

Comment: You just need to add the google maps sdk in your project's bundle. User doesn't need to do anything to be able to use google maps on his/her device.

Comment: Were you able to get it running? Did you see my note below about the size :) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Google Maps in your application through the SDK, there is **no** requirement for the user. They don't need to have the Google Maps app on their phone.

So yes, it will work straight away.

The only things you need to make sure is to make sure you configure the SDK as described in Google's [SDK Start Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start) and that you have an API key requested from Google and configured it in your app.

---

### Size impact

It is hard to say how the Google SDK impacts the size of your app, because Apple does a lot of optimization (e.g. If you allow [App Thinning](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html) it might be a lot smaller). I think for my apps it makes about a 3-10 MB difference.

iTunes Connect allows you to inspect the *estimated* size of the app. The screenshot is from an app I worked on that uses 13 different pods, including Google Maps.
[image: iTunes Connect showing estimated download and installation sizes of an app]

In order to see this go to `iTunes Connect > [Your App] > Activity > All Builds > [Select a Build] > App Store File Sizes`

Comment: Thank you for the repily Is this going to significantly increase the mb weight of my project ?